# Prolog IntList definition

Tags: list, prolog

> hill(+IntList) succeeds if IntList consists of monotonically increasing >integers followed by monotonically decreasing integers.  For example, >[1,2,5,8,11,6,3,-1] is a hill, but [1,2,5,8,11,6,9,3,-1] and [1,2,3,4,5,6] are >not hills.  You may assume that IntList contains only integers.

This is what I have done so far:

```
hill(List) :-
    increasing(List), decreasing(List).

increasing([H|Tail]) :-
    sm(H,Tail),
    increasing(Tail).
increasing([]).


decreasing([H|Tail]) :-
    gr(H,Tail),
    decreasing(Tail).

decreasing([]).

hill([]).

gr(X,[H|Tail]) :- X>H.
gr(X,[]).

sm(X,[H|Tail]) :- X<H.  
sm(X,[]).
```

But this doesn't work. The logic is: A list of numbers is `hill` IF it is `increasing` and then `decreasing`. How do I say that? This code does `increasing` and `decreasing`, but no list can be both `increasing` and `decreasing`.

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, i m not allowed to use any thing else other than primitive rules and facts.

Comment: How does your instructor define "primitive rules and facts"?

Comment: # The only pre-defined predicates you may use are arithmetic/comparison, member/2, length/2, and append/3 (you don't need to use these either if you don't want to).
# Do not use any non-declarative constructs.  This includes (but is not limited to) cut (!), assert/retract, not, and bagof/setof.

Comment: OK, thanks. I can't upvote this question now as I've hit the vote limit, but I'll try and remember to do it later. It's a well-written homework question, which is pretty rare on Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: :)Thanks.

I need to solve 9 more of this kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hill(L1) :- concatenate(L2,L3,L1), inc(L2), dec(L3).
dec([X|[Y|[]]]) :- X > Y.
dec([X|[Y|L]]) :- X > Y, dec([Y|L]).
inc([X|[Y|[]]]) :- Y > X.
inc([X|[Y|L]]) :- Y > X, inc([Y|L]).
concatenate([],L2,L2).
concatenate([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]) :- concatenate(L1,L2,L3).
```

This works :)

Comment: But in this case even hill([1,2,3,4,5]) is a hill which it shouldnt be.

Comment: Yeah, that looks good. One thing though: you just rewrote `append/3`, but your prof. said you could use the predefined version. :)

Comment: Actually, you might still have a problem. Is `[1, 2, 1]` supposed to be a hill? I couldn't tell from your description. Also, your latest code can give two solutions, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to give a complete, working solution to a homework problem, but I'll describe in words how I would proceed from the code you've got right now. Right now your `increasing` and `decreasing` predicates test the entire list. By your definition, though, a hill is neither entirely increasing nor entirely decreasing. I would modify these predicates to have two arguments instead of one. The additional argument would be bound to the tail of the list which is not does not satisfy the increasing/decreasing criteria. Then, I'd modify hill slightly to use the new argument of `increasing` to test decreasingness not of the entire list, but of the portion after the initial increasing subsequence. Finally, I would use the new argument of `decreasing` to verify that there are no non-decreasing elements after the decreasing subsequence.

If you need better hints, or if I seem to be talking nonsense (quite possible as I'm not that good with Prolog), just let me know and I'll try to clarify more.

**Edit based on OP's comments:** Alright, let's try something else. `L` is a hill if and only if `L` is a list of at least two monotone increasing elements ending with some element `M`, followed by a list of at least one monotone decreasing element starting with some element `N`, where `N < M`. Can you translate that description to Prolog clauses?

**Edit take two (SPOILER WARNING)**:

---

In your revised code, drop these three predicates: `increasing([]).`, `hill([]).`, and `hill(List) :- decreasing(List).`. This will almost give you a solution, but it will still fail, e.g. on `[3, 2, 1]`. Fixing this should be fairly easy, though.

Comment: Cant have two arguments that s not how Prof, wants it. Anyways, i got it, just need to fix it a little. Thanks.

Comment: Really? You can't make `increasing/1` and `decreasing/1` into `increasing/2` and `decreasing/2`? Hmm, that makes it a bit harder. Let me think...

Answer (score 1):

Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

We don't need to worry about getting recursion right if we use [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue) and [`chain/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html=) like this:

```
hill(Zs) :-
   Ascending0 =   [_|_],
   Descending = [M,_|_],
   append(Ascending0,Descending,Zs),
   append(Ascending0,[M],Ascending),
   chain(Ascending ,#<),
   chain(Descending,#>).
```

Let's run the queries the OP gave!

```
?- hill([1,2,5,8,11,6,3,-1]).
  true                               % as expected
; false.

?- hill([1,2,5,8,11,6,9,3,-1]).
false.                               % as expected

?- hill([1,2,3,4,5,6]).
false.                               % as expected
```