# Backtracking PROLOG:display all sub-sets with aspect of "mountain"

Tags: list, prolog, backtracking

Can you help me with this problem of backtracking in Prolog? 
The string `a1, ..., an` is given and it consists of distinct integers. 
    It is required to display all sub-sets with aspect of "mountain" 
    (a set has a "mountain" aspect if the elements increase to a certain 
    point and then decrease).
    Eg. 10 16 27 18 14 7.
 I know how to verify if a set has mountain aspect...
but now I need to display all solutions :(

```
% munte(list,integer,integer)
% rezolvare(list)

munte([],2,_).
munte([H|[]],2,_).
munte([H|[H1|T]],Pas,Nr):-
    Pas = 1,
    H<H1,!,
    L=[H1|T],
    Nr1=Nr+1,
    munte(L,Pas,Nr1).

munte([H|[H1|T]],Pas,Nr):-
    Pas = 1,
    H>H1,
    Nr>1,!,
    L=[H1|T],
    Pas1=Pas + 1,
    Nr1=Nr+1,
    munte(L,Pas1,Nr1).                       

munte([H|[H1|T]],Pas,Nr):-
    Pas = 2,
    H>H1,!,
    L=[H1|T],
    Nr1=Nr+1,
    munte(L,Pas,Nr1).

rezolvare(L1):-munte(L1,1,1).
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what those lines of code do and what exactly is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Note that this answer deals with **subsequences** of lists, not subsets of sets.

In the following we use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

We define `hillSubseq_in/2` based on [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915), [`(*)/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279182/4609915) and [`hill/1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32350888/4609915):

```
hillSubseq_in(Zs,Xs) :-
   tfilter(*,Xs,Zs),
   hill(Zs).
```

Sample query:

```
?- hillSubseq_in(Zs,[2,9,3,1,5,9,2]).
  Zs = [2,9,3,1]
; Zs = [2,9,3,2]
; Zs = [2,9,3]
; Zs = [2,9,1]
; Zs = [2,9,5,2]
; Zs = [2,9,5]
; Zs = [2,9,2]
; Zs = [2,3,1]
; Zs = [2,3,5,9,2]
; Zs = [2,3,5,2]
; Zs = [2,3,9,2]
; Zs = [2,3,2]
; Zs = [2,5,9,2]
; Zs = [2,5,2]
; Zs = [2,9,2]
; Zs = [3,5,9,2]
; Zs = [3,5,2]
; Zs = [3,9,2]
; Zs = [1,5,9,2]
; Zs = [1,5,2]
; Zs = [1,9,2]
; Zs = [5,9,2]
; false.
```