# Partitioning a List in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, sum, subset-sum

I am trying to create a Prolog predicate where, given a list, it is seen whether or not the list can be split into two lists that sum to the same amount.

I have a working list sum predicate, so I am using that within my partitioning predicate. I first tried to code the predicate to see if the first element of the list equals the sum of the rest of the list ([2,1,1]). This is what I have for that situation.

```
partitionable([X|Y]) :-
   sum([X],SUM),
   sum([Y],SUM2),
   SUM = SUM2.
```

However, I am getting this error message:

```
ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `[]/0' is not a function.
```

I would like to get this piece working before I delve into the recursion for the rest of the list, though I am confused on what this message is saying, since I have not written a `'[]/0' function`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I realized that I passed X and Y into the sum predicate as lists, when they should have been just passed as themselves, so I am no longer getting an error message. However, the predicate still returns false even if I pass in partitionable([2,1,1]) - this should return true. Could this be because of my sum predicate?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29398593/edit) your problem rather than elaborate in the comments, or it's going to get quite confusing. `X` is a single element, the head of the list `[X|Y]`, and `Y` is the tail of the list (another list). So `[Y]` is a list of one element, itself a single list. That's probably not what you want. You also need to make it clear whether ordering of elements matters. For example, should it succeed with the list, `[1,2,1]`?

Comment: The ordering of the list does matter, so only one partition can be made anywhere in the list which satisfies the sum constraint (so [1,2,1] would not work).

Answer (score 4):

To partition a list into two non-overlapping [subsequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence), 
we use `list_subseq_subseq/3`:

```
list_subseq_subseq([]    ,[]    ,[]).
list_subseq_subseq([X|Xs],[X|Ys],Zs) :-
   list_subseq_subseq(Xs,Ys,Zs).
list_subseq_subseq([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]) :-
   list_subseq_subseq(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

For performing integer arithmetics, we use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Let's put it all together! In the following sample query we partition the list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`:

```
?- Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
   sum(Xs,#=,Total),
   Half*2 #= Total,
   list_subseq_subseq(Xs,Ys,Zs),
   sum(Ys,#=,Half),
   sum(Zs,#=,Half).
  Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], Total = 28, Half = 14, Ys = [1,2,4,7], Zs = [3,5,6]
; Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], Total = 28, Half = 14, Ys = [1,2,5,6], Zs = [3,4,7]
; Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], Total = 28, Half = 14, Ys = [1,3,4,6], Zs = [2,5,7]
; Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], Total = 28, Half = 14, Ys = [1,6,7]  , Zs = [2,3,4,5]
; Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], Total = 28, Half = 14, Ys = [2,3,4,5], Zs = [1,6,7]
; Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], Total = 28, Half = 14, Ys = [2,5,7]  , Zs = [1,3,4,6]
; Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], Total = 28, Half = 14, Ys = [3,4,7]  , Zs = [1,2,5,6]
; Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], Total = 28, Half = 14, Ys = [3,5,6]  , Zs = [1,2,4,7]
; false.
```

Comment: What means disjoint for `list_subseq_subseq([a,a],Ys, Zs)`?

Comment: That would something inherently nondeterminate. Maybe for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: @false. I think  "non-overlapping subsequences"  fits better than "disjoint subsequences". When we say "partition" it should be clear that every item in `Xs` goes into exactly one of either `Ys` or `Zs`, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

It *keeps getting better!*

To non-deterministically partition lists, we don't need to implement a recursive auxiliary predicate like [`list_subseq_subseq/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) if we employ the right meta-predicate/predicate combination!

In this answer, we use [`tpartition/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) as the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) and 
the "reified wild-card" predicate `(*)/2` as the predicate passed to `tpartition/4`.  `(*)/2` can be defined like this:

```
_ * true.
_ * false.
```

Let's put `tpartition/4` to use with `(*)/2` and the [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) constraints [`(#=)/2` and `sum/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html):

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).   % use clp(FD) library
true.

?- ABs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],        % same data as in the earlier answer
   sum(ABs,#=,NN),
   N*2 #= NN,
   tpartition(*,ABs,As,Bs),
   sum(As,#=,N),
   sum(Bs,#=,N).
  NN = 28, N = 14, ABs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], As = [1,2,4,7], Bs = [3,5,6] 
; NN = 28, N = 14, ABs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], As = [1,2,5,6], Bs = [3,4,7]
; NN = 28, N = 14, ABs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], As = [1,3,4,6], Bs = [2,5,7]
; NN = 28, N = 14, ABs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], As = [1,6,7]  , Bs = [2,3,4,5]
; NN = 28, N = 14, ABs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], As = [2,3,4,5], Bs = [1,6,7]    
; NN = 28, N = 14, ABs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], As = [2,5,7]  , Bs = [1,3,4,6]    
; NN = 28, N = 14, ABs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], As = [3,4,7]  , Bs = [1,2,5,6]
; NN = 28, N = 14, ABs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], As = [3,5,6]  , Bs = [1,2,4,7]
; false.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also offer another solution for the partition problem. helper predicate helps to cut the list two list. For example [1,2,3] can be cutted down:

[1,2] (left side) and [3](right side) or

[3] (left side) and [1,2] (right side).

```
helper([],[],[],0,0).  
helper([X|XS],[X|L],R,SUML,SUMR):-helper(XS,L,R,SUMN,SUMR),SUML is SUMN+X. 
helper([X|XS],L,[X|R],SUML,SUMR):-helper(XS,L,R,SUML,SUMN),SUMR is SUMN+X.
partition(S,L,R):-helper(S,L,R,X,X).
```

Output is :

```
1 ?- partition([1,2,3,4],L,R).
L = [1, 4],
R = [2, 3] ;
L = [2, 3],
R = [1, 4] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that passing X as [X] is required, since X is just the element (the number 2 in your example).
Y on the other hand is a list in itself an should not be put in another list.
Here is the modified version:

```
partitionable([X|Y]) :- sum([X],SUM), sum(Y,SUM2), SUM=SUM2.
sum([X|Y],SUM) :- sum(Y, SUBSUM), SUM is SUBSUM + X.
sum([X],SUM) :- X=SUM.
```

`partitionable([2,1,1])` returns true in my case.

**Edit**:
Since you do not use `is/2` this may be an error in the `sum` predicate.

On another note: As I understand your question you do not require a solution for `partitionable` but the error message you received.
Nonetheless here is my take on implementing it (**possibly spoiler ahead**):

```
/* partitionable(X)
 * If a 2-partition of X exists where both sublists have the same sum, then X
 * is considered partitionable.
 */
partitionable(X) :- partition(X, A, B), sum(A, SUM), sum(B, SUM2), SUM =:= SUM2, !.

/* partition(X, A, B)
 * X is split in two lists A and B and will, during backtracking, bind A and B to
 * ALL permutations of the list partition, including permutations for each list.
 */
partition([], [], []).
partition([X|Y], A, B) :- partition(Y, R, B), extract(X, A, R).
partition([X|Y], A, B) :- partition(Y, A, R), extract(X, B, R).

/* extract(X, L, R)
 * Extracts exactly one element X from L and unify the result with R.
 */
extract(X, [H|T], R) :- X = H, R = T.
extract(X, [H|T], R) :- R = [H|R2], extract(X, T, R2).

sum([X|Y],SUM) :- sum(Y, SUBSUM), SUM is SUBSUM + X.
sum([X],SUM) :- X = SUM.
```

Comment: Ok, I understand why I need to put X in brackets and Y by itself. After changing it though, using anything but `partitionable([2,1,1]).` yields an error: ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `[]/0' is not a function. I am lost as to what is causing that to happen.

Comment: @red_student Could you please show some examples where the error is appearing? I understand this answer is not a correct solution for partitionable, but i don't get the error you are mentioning. What version of prolog do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm underthinking this, but...

If by "partition the list", you mean "cut the list in two, preserving order, rather than creating various permutations of the list),it doesn't seem like the solution should be any more complex than something like this:

```
partitionable( Ns ) :-
  append( Prefix , Suffix , Ns ) ,
  compute_sum(Prefix,Sum) ,
  compute_sum(Suffix,Sum) .

compute_sum( Ns , S ) :- compute_sum(Ns,0,S) .

compute_sum( []     , S , S ) .
compute_sum( [N|Ns] , T , S ) :- T1 is N+T , compute_sum(Ns,T1,S) .
```

If you want to avoid using built-ins, you could do something like this, which has the added benefits of elegance whilst minimizing list traversals:

```
partitionable( List ) :-
  sum_prefix( List , Sum , Sfx ) ,
  sum_prefix( Sfx  , Sum , []  ) .

sum_prefix( List , Sum , Suffix ) :- sum_prefix(List,0,Sum,Suffix) .

sum_prefix( Suffix   , Sum , Sum , Suffix ) .
sum_prefix( [H|List] , Acc , Sum , Suffix ) :-
  Acc1 is Acc+H ,
  sum_prefix(List,Acc1,Sum,Suffix)
  .
```